# Is there a built-in "deviation"-function in python?

Tags: python

I don't know the proper terminology for this, so please correct me if the term "deviation" is wrong for what I'm talking about, but I am wondering if there is a built-in function to deviate a value using standard mathematical operators in Python that works by passing it an original value, an operand and a modification value.

I would need this to specify a "deviation" at the top layer of a program which is later applied to a value that is dynamically retrieved.

What I currently have is a function like this:

```
def deviateValue(value, deviation):
    value = float(value)
    operand = deviation[0]
    modifier = float(deviation[1:])
    if operand == "+":
        value += modifier
    elif operand == "-":
        value -= modifier
    elif operand == "*":
        value *= modifier
    elif operand == "/":
        value /= modifier
    elif operand == "=":
        value = modifier
    else:
        logger.warning("WARNING: Operand not implemented:", operand)
        return False

    return value
```

...which works, but it sort of feels like something basic like this should already implemented somewhere in the base package.

So to sum up the question: Does a function like this already exist somewhere within the basic Python modules? At the very least, I could not find it in the `math` module.

Comment: *"..it sort of feels like something basic like this should already implemented somewhere in the base package"* I would not say that. What you are trying to do here does not strike me as common in any way.

Comment: I'm not seeing where this is different than just later doing dynamicValue += modifierValue Could you please clarify?

Comment: Btw, you are not looking for something like [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html), are you?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `a + b` you can also do `operator.add(a, b)`. With that in mind you now only have to create a mapping from your operator strings to the according `operator.*` functions, and call the result:

```
import operator

def deviate(first, operand, second):
    ops = {
        '+': operator.add,
        '-': operator.sub,
        '*': operator.mul,
        '/': operator.truediv,
        '//': operator.floordiv,
        '%': operator.mod,
    }

    return ops[operand](first, second)

# 2 + 3 = 5
deviate(2, '+', 3)
# 2 * 3 = 6
deviate(2, '*', 3)
# 10 % 3 = 1
deviate(10, '%', 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply evaluate a string that is generated from the three inputs like this:

```
original=2
operand='+'
modifier=3
eval(str(original)+operand+str(modifier))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would *not* recommend this, but it will do the job:

```
def deviateValue(v,d):
    try:
        return eval(str(v)+d)
    except:
        logger.warning("WARNING: Could not evaluate %r %s" % (v,d))
        return False
```